# SDL C++ IDE can't open .ttf file

Tags: c++, sdl, truetype

I included the ttf file into my project, I copied this ttf into the debug folder, and to the System32 folder, and I installed it on Windows. I used another C++ source  found on internet, It doesn't work as well. BUT If I run the binary directly from the "Debug" ( not from the IDE  ) folder it works correctly.

Im using CodeBlocks, SDL2.

Comment: The working directory doesn't seem where you think it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paths you use in your code are relative to the directory from which your app is ran.

If your .ttf file is in the same directory as your application, you should use `SDL_GetBasePath()` to figure out where that is:

```
char* p = SDL_GetBasePath();
if(p == nullptr) { /* TODO: error */ }
std::string ttfPath = std::string(p) + "myfont.ttf";
SDL_free(p); // TODO: exception safety
// now, you can open the file 
TTF_Font* f = TTF_OpenFont(ttfPath.c_str(), 42);
// ...
```